# Trouble getting information from DB, loosing information while using LIKE function SQL

Tags: sql

I am new to coding and i really need some help if u can have an idea from you guys. I am working on a WP Plugin which is basically an admin interface. I create a table based on my BD which contains differents information but I have some trouble with some sql request.
I have a lot of tables, I needed to combine them to get what I wanted to get something like this first :

| license key | license ID | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| def5002313131 | 1 | some text |
| def5056462131 | 1 | some text |
| def5064654631 | 1 | some text |
| def5646162131 | 2 | some text |
| def5541541531 | 3 | some text |

using the following code :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.license_key,1,15), W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.user_id, W551je5v_posts.post_author, W551je5v_postmeta.meta_value FROM W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses 
LEFT JOIN W551je5v_users ON W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.user_id = W551je5v_users.ID 
LEFT JOIN W551je5v_posts ON W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.user_id = W551je5v_posts.post_author
LEFT JOIN W551je5v_postmeta ON W551je5v_postmeta.post_id = W551je5v_posts.ID
WHERE W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.user_id IS NOT NULL AND W551je5v_users.ID IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY W551je5v_lmfwc_licenses.license_key
ORDER BY user_id;
```

getting meta_value from postmeta, every license information from license but i had to pass by the 2 others table to get to postmeta.
By grouping by license_key, I am only getting the first line of meta_value corresponding to the license_id.
In those meta_value, there is a mac adress that i have to get (that's the final point).
So i used LIKE function to get meta_value which had meta_key equal to 'mac' (meta_key is an other col in the postmeta table) `W551je5v_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'mac'`. But when I do it, I loose some of IDs cause they didn't have a mac adress and I still want to get them to create a table like this

| license key | license ID | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| def5002313131 | 1 | mac adress |
| def5056462131 | 1 | mac adress |
| def5064654631 | 1 | mac adress |
| def5646162131 | 2 | NULL |
| def5541541531 | 3 | mac adress |

I couldn't found any solution cause LIKE is only keeping the lines with an mac adress.

I tried also to GROUP_CONCAT every meta_value information and using REGEX to get the mac adress, but GROUP_CONCAT is limited in number of character and I am over the limit. I can't found how to use the SET @@global.group_concat_max_len = 1000000 on my website, if you have any ideas of how I can do it without using GROUP CONCAT or LIKE but something that is doing the same with keeping every lines, I would appreciate a lot.
Sorry for my bad english, and if I am not very clear, but I tried to explain it as much I as can, ask if u need more information.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.